# How do I convert a Microsoft Excel Online spreadsheet link into a CSV?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, if I have the following shareable link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsjFcmMcPoNYgRCnu_5rTiC5dz1t (which would lead to an Excel Online spreadsheet)

How could I modify that link so it gives me back a CSV format? (like Google Excel does)

P.S: The link above doesn't work, it's just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel Online does not currently support exporting to CSV.

> Workbooks in other formats, such as .csv format, are generally not supported in Excel Online.

Source: [Differences between using a workbook in the browser and in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-Excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6?CorrelationId=263ccfb8-b47c-4282-9ef9-13be480e4f93&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010369179).